# How to ensure that request arrived from our application

Tags: c#, security, request

we are building some internal system , that counts usage of specific software on specific date.

The software sends http request to the server with specific events , and then statistics created on this data.

How can "SIGN" , or ensure that request is coming from the application , and not was just reverse engineered and sent as fake.

I mean , as it designed currently , I can run application , see in some http proxy what data sent , create fake request , send to server , and it will be counted as valid one.

Anyone can suggest any idea pls ?

Thanks a lot stack gurus :)

Comment: You're looking for HTTPS with client certificates.  Beware that attackers can simply reverse-engineer your client cert too.

Comment: The problem that our tool is written in .net and even with obfuscation , gives pretty much readable code , that can be reversed. So even I will encrypt client certificate , or smthing in few good hrs of work , it will be decoded.

Comment: Maybe you have some idea , how to minimize their chances ?